# How to repeat a function without effecting repeating the token

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script

How do I modify the repeat loop function without it repeating the token variable in the function rowcount()?

```
function rowcount()
{ 
  var token = getAccessToken();
  var module = "sHistory";
  var rows = 0;
  var go = true;
  var i = 1;
  var data;
  
   
   while (go) {
    data = getRecordsByPage(i,200,token,module);
    
    if (Number(data.info.count) < 200) {
      go = false;
    };
    if ((i%10) == 0) {
       go = false; 
    }
    rows = Number(rows) + Number(data.info.count);
      i++;
   
      Logger.log(rows)
      }
      return rows
   }
  
  
function repeatloop()
{
  let counter = 0;

  for(var i = 1; i <= 93; i++)
      {
        {
        Utilities.sleep(10000);
        Logger.log(i);

        counter += rowcount();
        Logger.log(counter);
        }
      }
      return rowcount().rows;   
  }
```

What I am also trying to do is let the count continue because right now it goes in an increment of 2000, but I need it to continue like 200...400..600..800...1000...1200...1400...1600...1800...2000...2200. and it goes on until the loop stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the token a global variable like this:

```
var token;
function rowcount()
{
  var module = "sHistory";
  var rows = 0;
  var go = true;
  var i = 1;
  var data;
  
   
   while (go) {
    data = getRecordsByPage(i,200,token,module);
    
    if (Number(data.info.count) < 200) {
      go = false;
    };
    if ((i%10) == 0) {
       go = false; 
    }
    rows = Number(rows) + Number(data.info.count);
      i++;
   
      Logger.log(rows)
      }
      return rows
   }
  
  
function repeatloop()
{
  let counter = 0;
  token = getAccessToken();

  for(var i = 1; i <= 93; i++)
      {
        {
        Utilities.sleep(10000);
        Logger.log(i);

        counter += rowcount();
        Logger.log(counter);
        }
      }
      return rowcount().rows;   
  }
```

Or did I understand you wrong?

Comment: I think you miss understood me, so the function repeatloop() is repeating everything function rowcount(), that includes the token,which I think is an issue, because everytime the loop runs it refreshes the token every time which is causing issues, giving me an error of invalid token at certain intervals of the loop, and I think it is because the token gets refreshed every loop, and it is not supposed to, so my question is, how do I loop the function rowcount() rowcount without it affecting the looping of the token

Comment: @MrJnrDev Declare it as global variable. `var token = getAccessToken();` outside the function `rowcount()`

Comment: I tried the above and it still gives the same error

Comment: @MrJnrDev the rowcount() function is executed without refreshing the token in the code in the post so I can't see the problem

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the token as an **optional parameter**, insted to use *GLOBAL* variable:

```
function rowcount(_token = null)
{ 
  let token;
  if (_token) {token = _token;}
  else {token = getAccessToken();} 

  var module = "sHistory";
  var rows = 0;
  var go = true;
  var i = 1;
  var data;
  
   
   while (go) {
    data = getRecordsByPage(i,200,token,module);
    
    if (Number(data.info.count) < 200) {
      go = false;
    };
    if ((i%10) == 0) {
       go = false; 
    }
    rows = Number(rows) + Number(data.info.count);
      i++;
   
      Logger.log(rows)
      }
      return rows
   }
  
  
function repeatloop()
{
  let token = getAccessToken();
  let counter = 0;

  for(var i = 1; i <= 93; i++)
      {
        {
        Utilities.sleep(10000);
        Logger.log(i);

        counter += rowcount(token);
        Logger.log(counter);
        }
      }
      return rowcount(token).rows;   
  }
```